# Will this iteration converge to the Left singular vector and right singular vector of Highest singular value?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

I am constructing two sequences of vectors $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\dots,$  and $\mathbf{y}_1,\mathbf{y}_2,\dots,$ in the explained manner. All this vectors are unit-norm. Consider the $N\times N$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$. Then $\mathbf{x}_1$ is randomly initialized as $N\times 1$ unit-norm vector. Then $\mathbf{y}_1$ is found as
\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}_1=\arg \max_{\lvert\lvert\mathbf{y}_1\rvert\rvert=1} \mathbf{x}_1^H\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}_1
\end{align} 
Then $\mathbf{x}_2$ is found as 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}_2=\arg \max_{\lvert\lvert\mathbf{x}_2\rvert\rvert=1} \mathbf{x}_2^H\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}_1
\end{align} 
Then $\mathbf{y}_2$ is found as
\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}_2=\arg \max_{\lvert\lvert\mathbf{y}_2\rvert\rvert=1} \mathbf{x}_2^H\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}_2
\end{align} 
Thus $\mathbf{x}_i$ is found as
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}_i=\arg \max_{\lvert\lvert\mathbf{x}_i\rvert\rvert=1} \mathbf{x}_i^H\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}_{i-1}
\end{align} 
and $\mathbf{y}_i$ is found as 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}_i=\arg \max_{\lvert\lvert\mathbf{y}_i\rvert\rvert=1} \mathbf{x}_i^H\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}_{i}
\end{align} 
Will the sequences  $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\dots,$  and $\mathbf{y}_1,\mathbf{y}_2,\dots,$ converge to the left singular vector and right singular vector of matrix $\mathbf{A}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, starting with some given $y_0$,
$$
x_i=\arg\max_{\|x\|_2=1}x^*Ay_{i-1}, \quad y_i=\arg\max_{\|y\|_2=1}x_i^*Ay,
\quad i=1,2,\ldots,
$$
we have
$$
x_i=\frac{Ay_{i-1}}{\|Ay_{i-1}\|_2}, \quad y_i=\frac{A^*x_i}{\|A^*x_i\|_2}.
$$
Substituting one to the other,
$$
y_i=\frac{A^*x_i}{\|A^*x_i\|_2}=\frac{A^*Ay_{i-1}}{\|A^*Ay_{i-1}\|_2},
$$
and hence $(y_i)$ are vectors obtained by applying the power method to the matrix $A^*A$. In the similar way (by eliminating $y_{i-1}$ from the recursion), you can show that $(x_i)$ are iterations of the power method applied to $AA^*$. So, yes, provided that the maximal singular value of $A$ is simple and the initial guess is not unlucky, the vectors converge to the singular vectors associated with the maximal singular value of $A$.